# Appending File in a UD Function

Tags: file, append

I just defined a function to append a text file. it seems to be OK, except, at time of execution to Typing Text the Cursor starts from 'None', what the problem and how to remove the 'None'. However, this 'None' is not appended in txt file
here is my code

> def file_apend(fa,x):
> fa.write(x)
> fa.close()
> fa = open('whd.txt','a') x=input(print('Enter Text to Append in File....... '))
> file_apend(fa,x)

the OUT PUT is...

Enter Text to Append in File.......
None I can append here....

In Short HOW TO REMOVE THIS 'NONE'

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution from another answer. Here is my solution:

```
def file_apend(fa,x):
    fa.write(x)
    fa.close()
fa = open('whd.txt','a')
(print('Enter Text to Append in File....... '))
x=input()   
file_apend(fa,x)
```

I used `print()` in a separate line.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).